# ThreadPoolExecutor takes a longer time than threading module

Tags: python, multithreading, module, timing, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to learn threading with Python. I just run to the dummy function with the 'threading' module and the 'concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor' module.

However with 'threading' module code finishes in ~4 seconds...

```
from time import perf_counter as counter
from time import sleep
import threading

start = counter()


def dummy(idx):
    print(f"Dummy {idx} counting to 3k...")

    c = 0
    while c < 3e3:
        # print(f'[{idx}] - {c}')
        c += 1
        sleep(0.001)

    print(f"Dummy {idx} finished his job succesfully.")


threads = []

for i in range(10):
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=dummy, args=[i]))
    threads[i].start()

for i in range(10):
    threads[i].join()

# Finished in 4 seconds...

finish = counter()

print(f"Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} second(s).")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Dummy 0 counting to 3k...
Dummy 1 counting to 3k...
Dummy 2 counting to 3k...
Dummy 3 counting to 3k...
Dummy 4 counting to 3k...
Dummy 5 counting to 3k...
Dummy 6 counting to 3k...
Dummy 7 counting to 3k...
Dummy 4 finished his job succesfully.
Dummy 8 counting to 3k...
4 DONE!
Dummy 3 finished his job succesfully.
Dummy 9 counting to 3k...
3 DONE!
Dummy 0 finished his job succesfully.
0 DONE!
Dummy 1 finished his job succesfully.
1 DONE!
Dummy 5 finished his job succesfully.
5 DONE!
Dummy 7 finished his job succesfully.
7 DONE!
Dummy 2 finished his job succesfully.
2 DONE!
Dummy 6 finished his job succesfully.
6 DONE!
Dummy 8 finished his job succesfully.
8 DONE!
Dummy 9 finished his job succesfully.
9 DONE!
Finished in 8.32 second(s).
```

but other module takes ~8 seconds even I wrote same program.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Tpe
from concurrent.futures import as_completed as ac
from time import perf_counter as counter
from time import sleep

start = counter()

def dummy(idx):
    print(f"Dummy {idx} counting to 3k...")

    c = 0
    while c < 3e3:
        c += 1
        sleep(0.001)

    print(f"Dummy {idx} finished his job succesfully.")
    return f"{idx} DONE!"


with Tpe() as executor:
    trds = [executor.submit(dummy, i) for i in range(10)]

    for r in ac(trds):
        print(r.result())


finish = counter()

print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} second(s).')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Dummy 0 counting to 3k...
Dummy 1 counting to 3k...
Dummy 2 counting to 3k...
Dummy 3 counting to 3k...
Dummy 4 counting to 3k...
Dummy 5 counting to 3k...
Dummy 6 counting to 3k...
Dummy 7 counting to 3k...
Dummy 8 counting to 3k...
Dummy 9 counting to 3k...
Dummy 4 finished his job succesfully.
Dummy 2 finished his job succesfully.
Dummy 9 finished his job succesfully.Dummy 6 finished his job succesfully.

Dummy 3 finished his job succesfully.
Dummy 1 finished his job succesfully.
Dummy 0 finished his job succesfully.
Dummy 5 finished his job succesfully.
Dummy 7 finished his job succesfully.
Dummy 8 finished his job succesfully.
Finished in 4.3 second(s).
```

I thought each code will take ~4 seconds. Do you have an idea, why ThreadPoolExecutor is taking so long?

Comment: You seem to have switched the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

A thread pool doesn't just start a new thread for every job. It has a *pool* of worker threads that it uses to execute the jobs you submit, and that pool can only grow to a certain maximum limit. If all the workers are busy (even if what they're busy with is sleeping) and the `max_workers` limit has been reached, further jobs will have to wait until a running job finishes.

The default `max_workers` computation varies between Python versions, but [currently](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor), it's `min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4)`. Judging by the output, we can see that your thread pool has a `max_workers` of 8. It cannot run 10 jobs in parallel. The last 2 jobs have to wait until some of the earlier jobs finish before they can run.